# Where have my items disappeared to?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I made a system with my quarry. Quarry output is put into an enderchest, which is put into a diamond chest, and that is pumped into my barrel system, like so:
[image]
[image]

But alas, all my barrels and my diamond chest are full.

[image]

As well as this diamond chest.

[image]

But I'm not an idiot. While I used Buildcraft pipes to pipe things to my barrel system, you will notice that I used pneumatic tubes for my barrels. So, where are my items!?!? Are they stuck in the transposer?

---

UPDATE: It looks like a chunk reset deleted all of my stuff. *sigh*.
[image]

Comment: if the quarry has nowhere to send items is will spit them out this will have happened when the enderchest filled up

Comment: The quarry chunk despawned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they're landing on the transposer at the bottom of the pit, not getting pulled in because it's full, and despawning.

Really, this needs the BC pipes removed to work better, and there's no reason to start with a RedPower2 transposer, switch to Buildcraft pipes, then go back to RP2 tubes. Just use RP2 tubes throughout. That won't prevent problems when the Ender chest fills up, but it will stop this side of the system from leaking items.

To prevent the Ender chest from filling up, you really need more item overflow storage. There should be enough chests that you keep empty at the end of your tube system that they can store about half the entire quarry output, if necessary. I would combine that with an overflow just before it for just cobblestone (using a filter) that would redirect cobble you can't store into a recycler or an obsidian pipe/void pipe assembly, since you don't want your emergency overflow to fill up with cobble and render it useless.

To keep the overflow useful, always make sure to empty it before starting a new quarry.

Comment: @jeffreylin I don't think its buffer is even a stack.

Comment: I just added a chest to the system and ~1/2 a chest of stuff disappeared. The update in the question shows what *really* happened to the rest of the stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If you switched to using a RP2 Relay, which will eject the items into the tubes as soon as there is a destination, you would be able to see the items getting stuck in the Relay (because there is no destination, as @SevenSidedDie suggested).

Remember, because Buildcraft pipes will still pop items out if there is no room, you need to have RP all the way. (They have gotten better from how they were in the past, but RP has destination targeting.)

Example setup based on yours: (**Basically**, the relay replaces the first shown intermediary diamond chest)

```
Ender Chest> | Transposer> | Relay> | Pipe system
             |    Clock^   |        |
```

Where a `|` is a block border.

If you want some sort of alarm when all the chests fill up, try to do something behind a Restriction Tube, made from Pneumatic Tube + Iron. It counts as 5000 blocks in the routing, so it will always be farthest. You can then hook it up to <strike>a howler alarm</strike> a prominent lamp.

Comment: If there are still BC pipes involved, items will pop out and despawn if the relay refuses them.

Comment: @Seven Yes, I forgot to mention that. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Relays don't automatically suck items; they're just a chest that automatically ejects its contents. They're useful for feeding BC pipes into a RP2 network.